# Get-ChildItem -path "\\Servername.net\FolderName\SubFolderName\" error with UNC path

Tags: powershell

I am using Get-ChildItem with a path to navigate to a common file share.
I was able to navigate to common file share from my local machine without any issues but when I deploy this code into the PROD server, there I am running into **Cannot find path** issue.

Power Shell Command:

```
Get-ChildItem   "\\servername.net\abcd\"
```

Error:

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\\servername.net\abcd\' because it does not exist.
At line:2 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem   '\\servername.net\abcd\'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\servername.net\abcd\:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Not sure if anyone experienced this issue and how to resolve these environmental issues.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[Power shell error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyP4P.png)

Comment: It would seem it can't find the servers hostname. Could be any of many reasons, but not necessarily programming related.

Comment: When I simply copied file share into file explorer in PROD box, I was able to navigate to target directory without issues.
But erroring out when trying to navigate from PowerShell.

Comment: This looks like a provider issue. When you are using the provider, `SqlServer`, it appears some functionality is not available. I bet if you went back to a file system, the experience would be different. Try `cd c:` first and then run your command.

Comment: @Sandy, If my assumptions are correct in the previous comment, a workaround is `push-location c:; Get-ChildItem   "\\servername.net\abcd\"; pop-location`. I don't know if that is ideal

Comment: I would try opening cmd, do an `nslookup servername.net` and then use the IP instead of the name and see if that works.

Comment: @AdminOfThings I have verified Get-ChildItem C:  and its working fine to navigate to mapped directories and local directories without any issues.

I have even mapped servername.net\abcd as local directory in PROD machine for testing and Powershell was able to navigate to the mapped directory of the same file path without any issues. getting issues when trying to navigate using UNC path.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot, I believe this to be a limitation of `Get-ChildItem` accessing UNC Paths while the current location is a `SqlServer` provider. I see a few options:

1. Map a `PSDrive` to the UNC path so that `Get-ChildItem` has a `FileSystem` provider to work with directly.

   ```
   New-PSDrive -Name Z -Root "\\servername.net\abcd" -PSProvider FileSystem
   Get-ChildItem Z:
   ```
2. Use a different method to retrieve files and directories.

   ```
   [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFileSystemEntries("\\servername.net\abcd")
   ```
3. Use the location stack to go into a `FileSystem`. Then return to your previous `PSDrive`.

   ```
   Push-Location C:
   Get-ChildItem "\\servername.net\abcd"
   Pop-Location
   ```

Comment: I will try to do this and let you know the outcome here.
Thanks much for your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you AdminOfThings, I am actually implementing ps new drive approach to take full advantage of get-childitems properties.

Comment: I have created new POSDrive with name ARCHIVE
I was able to navigate through directories to retrieve all files but when it comes to final zipping the below statement is failing as the program is converting below 
"ARCHIVE:BKP\FIleName_20190326.csv" to its actual UNC path and failing with the very original error message I have posted.
Back to square one 

Error Message:
Error: Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\servername.net\abcd\' because it does not exist.
Cmnd:
Compress-Archive -path  "ARCHIVE:BKP\FIleName_20190326.csv" -DestinationPath "ARCHIVE:BKP\2019-03.zip" -update

Comment: There should be a \ after ARCHIVE:

Comment: Yah did added \ in the following command and still PowerShell is taking full UNC path and failing to connect "ARCHIVE:\BKP\FIleName_20190326.csv"

Comment: Error 
Compress-Archive -path  "ARCHIVE:\BKP\FileName__20190326.csv" -DestinationPath "ARCHIVE:\BKP\2019-03.zip" -update
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 
'\\servername.net\FOlder\SubFOlder\BKP\FileName__20190326.csv' because it does not exist.
At C:\....\.soft.PowerShell
+     $dirContents = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $sourceDirPath -Recurse
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\ServerName....ED_20190326.csv:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Answer (score 0):

After evaluating the environments found that these UNC path issues are happening because of Domain differences.

My laptop and archive file share are residing in the same domain, and that's how archiving script was working without any issues.
Whereas the PROD server where I have deployed the script is residing in a different domain.

Resolved the issue by identifying another PROD server with the same domain name as the archive file share and deployed the script using task schedular.